# Update existing primary child when child from same parent is inserted

Tags: apex, trigger

Parent: Opportunity
Child: Opportunity Member
I want to update an existing child of an opportunity if a field with the name primary is true on the existing child(Primary child) when a new child is inserted. We can only have one primary member(child record ) for the opportunity.  There is a field Amount on the Opportunity Member object and I want to update this field by subtracting the Amount of New Opportunity member(that we are inserting) from Primary Opportunity Member(an existing record).

My Code is working fine for a single record but not working as expected for bulk operation. Please help

```
Public class OppotunityMemberTriggerhandler{
 
   public static void afterInsert(List<Opportunity_Member__c> newoppMember){
          Set<Id> oppIdSet = new Set<Id>();
          List<Opportunity_Member__c> memberList = new List<Opportunity_Member__c>();
          Map<id,Opportunity_Member__c> oppMemberMap = new Map<id,Opportunity_Member__c>();
          List<Opportunity_Member__c> updatedMemberList = new List<Opportunity_Member__c>();
          
          
          for(Opportunity_Member__c newMember : newoppMember){
             oppIdSet.add(newMember.Opportunity__c);
          }
          if(oppIdSet.size()>0){
             memberList = [SELECT id,Amount__c,Opportunity__c,Primary__c FROM Opportunity_Member__c WHERE Opportunity__c IN :oppIdSet AND Primary__c = True ];
          }
          for(Opportunity_Member__c member : memberList){
            oppMemberMap.put(member.Opportunity__c,member);

          }
          for(Opportunity_Member__c oppMember : newoppMember){
              if(oppMember.Primary__c == False){
                for(Opportunity_Member__c primaryMember : memberList){
                    primaryMember.Amount__c = oppMemberMap.get(oppMember.Opportunity__c).Amount__c - oppMember.Amount__c;
                    updatedMemberList.add(primaryMember);
                 }
             }
          }
          update updatedMemberList;
   }    
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109579/discussion-on-question-by-manu-kumar-update-existing-primary-child-when-child-fr).

Comment: Note that answer posts need to be _complete_ answers for Salesforce Stack Exchange. Comments are to request clarification, and discussion should take place in chat. Please update the question via an [edit] if discussion produces clarification to help the community find an answer.